# How can I convert one value from int to string within an array

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, string

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBzAd.png)I want to make my chart **data.addColumn ('string', 'hour');** must be a string.
In my request it is an int.

```php
$temp_array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $temp_array = array(strval($row["hour"]), $row["min"], $row["max"], $row["Avg"]);
}
```

result now: "["6","30.0","30.0","30.0"]"
want only the first one("6") between quotes.

[php code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBzAd.png)

[javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqizv.png)

Comment: See [Type Casting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting).

Comment: This question is unclear and lacks sufficient debugging details to be useful to future researchers.  Adding details as comments under answers is not how question details should be posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `strval()` to convert integer value to string. For example:

```
$temp_array[] = array( strval($row["hour"]), strval($row["min"]));
```

Comment: I am sorry, but seems not to work. I read somewhere that you can't use this in an array?

Comment: @ArjanG I believe what you read is that you can't use strval() ON an array. As in, it can't turn an array into a string. It does, however, work INSIDE an array. I tried it myself just now.

Comment: Yes, I think your right, but unfortunately this solution doesn't work for me

Comment: FYI this does work: https://3v4l.org/p7O12

Comment: your example also works on my environment.
I'll have to look a bit further as to why it doesn't work in my code.

Comment: When I try this: ```$temp_array[] = array(  strval($row["hour"]), $row["min"], $row["max"], $row["Avg"]);``` 
the result is => string(83) "[["23","20.6","20.6","20.6"],["3","17.0","21.2","19.1"],["6","30.0","30.0","30.0"]]" and all values has quotes?

Comment: FYI, the reason it didn't work before was because I had used 'JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK' => $temp_array = json_encode($temp_array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

Comment: @ArjanG share screenshot

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
$temp_array = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $temp_array[] = array( (string)$row["hour"], $row["min"], $row["max"], $row["Avg"]);
}
```

Comment: sorry, but seems not to work.
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Type mismatch. Value 23 does not match type string in column index 0

Comment: @ArjanG you are talking about a JavaScript error message here, while we are discussing PHP code. No one here besides you currently knows what you _do_ with this `$temp_array` afterwards.

Comment: When I do an ```var_dump($temp_array);``` =>  string(83) "[["23","20.6","20.6","20.6"],["3","17.0","21.2","19.1"],["6","30.0","30.0","30.0"]]"   and all values has quotes. 

Afterwards I do : ``` $temp_array = json_encode($temp_array); ```
and than in Java: ```var json_arr = <?php echo json_encode($temp_array); ?>; data.addRows(JSON.parse(json_arr));```

Comment: FYI, the reason it didn't work before was because I had used 'JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK' => $temp_array = json_encode($temp_array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

Answer (score 0):

`strval($row["hour"])` should do the trick.

Comment: Surely you know by now that the answer is considered low quality unless you have an explanation and/or a reference.  :-)

Comment: @RohitGupta Sure, but to be quite honest, some things are very self-explenatory. If someone asks, "How do I turn a value into a string," why would I explain, "this turns a value into a String"? It's a given.

Comment: If you post a self-explanatory answer as a single function solution in 2022, you can be fairly certain that you are answering a duplicate question.   Please don't do this.  When you answer a page that is later closed as a duplicate, you will prevent the [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) from doing its important work.

Comment: For your information: [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)

Comment: @mickmackusa as i am not authorized to mark questions as duplicate, my only alternative option is to ignore said question. i'd rather take the chance i might be helping someone by answering it.

Comment: You have unlocked the privilege to flag a question as a duplicate -- that will be infinitely more helpful than posting redundant content.  Every time you flag a duplicate instead of answering, you are helping Stack Overflow to be a better platform for sharing knowledge.